# R - data frame lookup and is.na handling

Tags: r

I have the following 2 data frames in R

```
d1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,NA), var2 = c(NA, 2), var3 = c(3,3))
max <- data.frame(var1 = 10, var2 = 5, var3 = 5)

  > d1
  var1 var2 var3
1    1   NA    3
2   NA    2    3

  > max
  var1 var2 var3
1   10    5    5
```

for each row in d1, I want to consider only the columns with non NA values. For those columns I want to lookup the corresponding value in the 'max' dataframe and take the sum of those values and add them as a new column in d1.

Output should look like this

```
  > d1
  var1 var2 var3 max_sum
1    1   NA    3      15
2   NA    2    3      10
```

I would start with a for loop through all rows from d1 and create my "max_sum" column

```
for (row in 1:nrow(d1)) {
    d1[row, "max_sum"] <- #code
}
```

Comment: How do you go from `1,NA,3` and `10,5,5` to `15`? Is it just `10+0+5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication

```
cbind(d1,
      "max_sum" = (!is.na(d1)) %*% t(max))
#  var1 var2 var3 max_sum
#1    1   NA    3      15
#2   NA    2    3      10
```

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. Just tried without the `+`and it is actually not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_sum <- vector()  

for(i in 1:nrow(d1)) {

   sum <- sum(max[c(!is.na(d1[i,]))])

   max_sum[i] <- sum

}

d1$max_sum <- max_sum
d1

  var1 var2 var3 max_sum
1    1   NA    3    15
2   NA    2    3    10
```

Comment: "virtual -1" for assigning the return value from `sum` in a variable named ... `sum` :-) ... (why not just do `max_sum[i] <- sum(max[...])`? ... and I recognize this is a continuation from the OP's use of `max` as a variable name)

Comment: @r2evans You are right. But it solves the problem :) . However, I like this site because always some people offers a faster and more accurate solution. It feeds me as well ;)